# How to use lightbox2 for multiple galleries

Tags: gallery, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm using this lightbox http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/, but there is problem with it that we can't use multiple image galleries, its showing all the images of other groups also, but i want separate galleries for all groups, is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you have a group of related images that you would like to combine into a set, use the same data-lightbox attribute value for all of those images and a different data-lightbox attribute for any other groups of images.

For example:

gallery 1:

```
<a href="images/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="set1">Image #2</a>
<a href="images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="set1">Image #3</a>
<a href="images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="set1">Image #4</a>
```

gallery 2:

```
<a href="images/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="set2">Image #5</a>
<a href="images/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="set2">Image #6</a>
<a href="images/image-7.jpg" data-lightbox="set2">Image #7</a>
```

etc......

Answer (score 0):

Try this Gallery Library called [BlueImp Gallery LightBox](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery)

here you can use multiple galleries and each gallery wont mingle with others still you can merge altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Gallery1

```
<a href="images/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip1">Image #1</a>
```

Gallery2

```
<a href="images/image-7.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip2">Image #11</a>
```